# How can I enable intellisense for Vue 3 component library created using JS instead of TS when using Volar extension in main project?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, intellisense, volar

I have created a Vue 3 component library using JavaScript instead of TypeScript. Now, I want to use the Volar extension in my main project to provide intellisense for the components created in the library. However, I couldn't find any solid implementations or documentation online for achieving this.

How can I enable intellisense for a Vue 3 component library created using JavaScript and using Volar extension in the main project?